# What is the best way to work with time interval using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am struggling with some MongoDB related queries (or modeling).
I am moving from a SQL database to MongoDB.
So far so good, but there is a tricky problem I couldn't find a good solution.

I have the following structure on my **parking** collection right now.

```
{
    _id: 5e00f403a663466329c78c5a,
    checkin_date: "2018-01-02T08:43:20.000+00:00",
    checkout_date: "2018-01-02T11:07:16.000+00:00",
    fare_amount: 10,
    license_num: blabla
}
```

At some point, I need to be able to group all **parking** info in a time interval way, so I would be able to count the number of cars in certain period of time on my parking, for example.

Using the info above, I would need to see that for this specific entry, this car was on my parking between:

- 2018-01-02 8AM - 2018-01-02 9AM
- 2018-01-02 9AM - 2018-01-02 10AM
- 2018-01-02 10AM - 2018-01-02 11AM

with that, it would be possible to count the number of parked cars between:

- 2018-01-02 8AM - 2018-01-02 9AM
- 2018-01-02 9AM - 2018-01-02 10AM
- 2018-01-02 10AM - 2018-01-02 11AM

My question is: is that the best way to store info? Is there a better way? How could I make this time interval query possible for my case?

Comment: Please save datetime in timestamp

Comment: I posted an answer. Is it useful?

Comment: hey guys, thanks for your help (sorry, I am on vacation and just saw the answers now).
They helped me a lot @prasad_

Tried to upvote your answer but it seems I don't have enough reputation :(

anyway, thank you!

Comment: Did my answer answer your question?

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... able to count the number of cars in certain period of time on my
>   parking, ...

The query is based upon the `start` and `end` date-time; this is the *period of time*.

Then, get the cars with:

- `check-in` and `check-out` within `start` and `end`
- `check-in` before `start` and `check-out` after `end`
- `check-in` is within and `check-out` is outside `start/end`
- `check-in` is outside and `check-out` is within `start/end`

The sum of all these gives you the total cars in the parking within the time period.

The query predicate will be like this:

```
var predicate = { $or: [ 
 { $and: [ { in: { $gte: start } }, { out: { $lte: end } } ] }, 
 { $and: [ { in: { $lt: start } }, { out: { $gt: end } } ] }, 
 { $and: [ { in: { $gte: start } }, { in: { $lte: end } }, { out: { $gt: end } } ] }, 
 { $and: [ { in: { $lt: start } }, { out: { $gte: start } }, { out: { $lte: end } } ] } 
] }
```

*NOTE:* For brevity I used `in` for `checkin_date` and `out` for `checkout_date`.

The query parameters, the time period, for example:

```
var start = "2019-12-25T09:00:00.000+00:00"
var end = "2019-12-25T17:00:00.000+00:00"
```

These are hours between 9AM and 5PM on 25th Dec, 2019.

The following query will return the number of cars in the specified time period:

```
db.parking.find( predicate ).count()
```

With the following test data of `11` entries you will get a count of `10` cars; the entry `_id: 6` will be excluded.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "veh" : "car-1", "in" : "2019-12-25T08:00:00.000+00:00", "out" : "2019-12-25T10:00:00.000+00:00" }
{ "_id" : 2, "veh" : "car-3", "in" : "2019-12-25T13:00:00.000+00:00", "out" : "2019-12-25T14:00:00.000+00:00" }
{ "_id" : 3, "veh" : "car-4", "in" : "2019-12-25T13:00:00.000+00:00", "out" : "2019-12-25T15:00:00.000+00:00" }
{ "_id" : 4, "veh" : "car-5", "in" : "2019-12-25T14:00:00.000+00:00", "out" : "2019-12-25T16:00:00.000+00:00" }
{ "_id" : 5, "veh" : "car-4", "in" : "2019-12-25T14:00:00.000+00:00", "out" : "2019-12-25T18:00:00.000+00:00" }
{ "_id" : 6, "veh" : "car-0", "in" : "2019-12-25T06:00:00.000+00:00", "out" : "2019-12-25T08:00:00.000+00:00" }
{ "_id" : 7, "veh" : "car-1", "in" : "2019-12-25T17:00:00.000+00:00", "out" : "2019-12-25T18:00:00.000+00:00" }
{ "_id" : 8, "veh" : "car-9", "in" : "2019-12-25T12:00:00.000+00:00", "out" : "2019-12-25T12:00:00.000+00:00" }
{ "_id" : 9, "veh" : "car-x", "in" : "2019-12-25T17:00:00.000+00:00", "out" : "2019-12-26T01:00:00.000+00:00" }
{ "_id" : 10, "veh" : "car-y", "in" : "2019-12-24T12:00:00.000+00:00", "out" : "2019-12-25T12:00:00.000+00:00" }
{ "_id" : 11, "veh" : "car-z", "in" : "2019-12-25T08:00:00.000+00:00", "out" : "2019-12-25T22:00:00.000+00:00"}
```

> My question is: is that the best way to store info? Is there a better
>   way? How could I make this time interval query possible for my case?

The way you are storing the data (as it is) looks alright. Ideally, the `checkin_date` and `checkout_date` should be [MongoDB Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/index.html) field types.

The example above shows the time interval query.